# Выделение запятыми "тоже мне"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятую в этом предложени :"Тоже мне(,) она меч принесла, лучше бы золото". Я нашёл в Интернете, что "тоже мне" не обособляется, например, в предложении "Тоже мне друг". Но в первом случаем мне кажется, что обособление нужно. Как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тоже мне, она меч принесла, лучше бы золото.

Или: Тоже мне,  меч она принесла, лучше бы золото.

Междометное сочетание со значением иронии, обособляется факультативно, что видно из примеров.

Тоже мне достопримечательность! Кладбище. Тоже мне сыщик! Тоже мне Раскольников…

Тоже мне, тень отца Гамлета! ― фыркнул начмед. Тоже мне, частный владелец! Тоже мне, полиция называется, ничего вы не знаете!